# Timer function doesn't start with eventlistener

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a game where once the user clicks 'begin', the timer will start and the user will be redirected to a new page.

so far, the user is being redirected to a new page, but the timer function is not counting down. I've got an error in my console log displaying

**script.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
at HTMLDocument. (script.js:20)**

this is the js code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const timeLeftDisplay = document.querySelector("#timer");
    const beginbtn = document.querySelector("#beginBtn");

    let secondsLeft = 45

    function countDown(){
        window.location.href = "questions.html"
        setInterval(function(){

            if (secondsLeft <= 0) {
                clearInterval(secondsLeft)
                window.location.href = "https://twitter.com"
            }
            timeLeftDisplay.innerHTML = timeLeftDisplay
            secondsLeft -=1

        },1000)
    }
    beginbtn.addEventListener('click', countDown)
})
```

this is the HTML page that the user will be redirected to

```
 <body>
    <header class="container mt-5">
        <div class = "row justify-content-end">
            <h6>time:</h6>
            <h6 id = "timer"></h6>
        </div>
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col">
          <h1 class="text-center">questions</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <h6 id = "question"></h6>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center mt-2" id = questionContain>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-lg" id = "choiceOne">
           
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

this is the home page with the begin button

```
  <main>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div>
            <button
           
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-outline-info btn-lg"
              id="beginBtn"
            >
              Begin
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: you don't have an element with the id beginBtn on the second page.

Comment: the begin button shouldn't show on the second page. Do I still need it on the second page, even if I hide it?

Comment: the issue is with the id as JS didn't find an element with the specified id.

Comment: even if I added the id to the second page, and hide the element, the timer won't start or display the seconds left

Answer (score 0):

change `timeLeftDisplay.innerHTML = timeLeftDisplay` to `timeLeftDisplay.innerHTML = secondsLeft;` and move `window.href` inside if function. And add element with `id="timer"`. Also add `;` semicolons after each statements

Comment: I changed the timeLeftDisplay. But the first window.href that directs the user to the next page after they click the begin button, should be in the if statement. Also, where would I add the id="timer"?

Answer (score 0):

If the browser is refreshing when it loads the second page your JS function is no longer executed. You should just call your countDown() function on the second page inside of the DOMContentLoaded listener.

Comment: okay, but how would I call the function just on my second page?

Comment: // Call function on page load 
// Make sure your countDown function exists on this page 
`window.onload = function() {
  countDown();
};`

Comment: sorry, I'm not quite sure where I how I call that function on that specific page. Both pages share the same js file.

Comment: if I add the window.onload  function into the countdown function, it refreshes the page second page over and over again.

Comment: If the browser is refreshing once the user begins and you are using the same JS file, you could check the HREF and execute your countDown function if the user is on the second page. `let url = window.location.href;

window.onload = function() {   
    if(url.indexOf("secondpage") !== -1) {
        countDown();
    } 
};`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oksimone/eroba2pz/ this is what it looks like so far. Not sure if I'm executing the function correctly

Comment: @oksimone Here is an updated fiddle that is working. You needed to move some of your logic outside of the countDown() function. https://jsfiddle.net/3ur96hbm/. Please upvote and mark correct if this works for you.

Comment: So, the countdown works, but not in the way that it should. The begin button (which is on the first page, not shown in JS fiddle) should redirect you to the page that says 'questions' and then the countdown should start.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle. There just isn't a "questions" page for it to go to. Should work perfectly in your local project or wherever you have these files. https://jsfiddle.net/0ocxtqre/1/

Comment: I appreciate the help! But the button still doesn't function the way it should. Is there something else in need to change in the code for the button to redirect the user to the questions.html page?

Comment: Make sure your addEventListener is calling the new begin() function. `beginbtn.addEventListener("click", begin);`

Comment: Thanks Ross! I just upvoted your comment. I appreciate all your help!